# What is common shortcut for "quantity"?

Tags: abbreviations

I found on an invoice the shortcut `QTTY` that stands for the word **quantity**.

Simplified part of the invoice:

```
Item      |    QTTY Unit | Unit Price |Total Price
Product X |       2      |   100.00   |   200.00
...
```

Would you use QTTY or QTY? Or any other form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that QTY is used more commonly, though looking through a handful of invoices I have to hand, they all use **quantity** instead of an abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Just say `Unit Count` for your fixed column.  And please don’t abbreviate *quantity*.